# Print message in Unity console when a GameObject hits a trigger? Unity5/2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a "Game" for school, and I need to tally votes. I'm using unity to have characters jump on buttons to count the votes and move on to the next question. This is what I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Vote1 : MonoBehaviour {

    private int vote1;
    public GameObject hero_1;

    void Start () {
        vote1 = 0;
    }

    void Update () {
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "PlayerObject"){
            vote1 = vote1 + 1;
            print("One Vote Added");
        }
    }
}
```

This *should* be adding +1 when "hero_1" stands on the button, and displaying the message "One Vote Added" in the console, but that's not what's happening. What am I doing wrong?

**Updated The Code**

now uses OnCollisionEnter2D, and still doesn't work as intended. What am I missing still?

Comment: Does `Console.WriteLine` work?

Comment: What does that print() function look like? also the vote1 = vote1 + 1; could be vote1++ or vote1 +=1;

Comment: Console.WriteLine doesn't work either.

Comment: [From the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html) *Trigger events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a rigidbody attached*  I don't know what that means but it sure sounds important.

Comment: I have a box with a boxcollider2d set to trigger, and a "hero_1" set as PlayerObject. When the hero moves over the box this should trigger the event of vote=vote+1 and putting "One Vote Added" in the console. When he leaves I also want the vote to go back to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `print` is a method defined in `MonoBehaviour` to print to the Unity console, I'm going to assume that you are in fact looking in the Unity console for the output, and nothing is showing up. That means that either `OnTriggerStay` is not getting called, or the collider's root does not have the `PlayerObject` tag.

`OnTriggerStay` is called when a 3D physics body is inside of a trigger. Make sure that the vote GameObject has the Vote1 component on it, and its collider has "Is Trigger" checked.

Also make sure that the object has a physics body and collider which is *not* a trigger. The object's root transform (i.e. the one in the hierarchy without any parents) should have the `PlayerObject` tag. If the player is inside of a parent container, then `transform.root` will get that parent rather than the player itself.

Also, make sure that collisions between the two items are not being filtered out via Edit->Project Settings->Physics->Layer Collision Matrix.

Last, make sure everything is enabled!

**Note**: You are using `OnTriggerStay` which will be hit once per frame while the player is in the trigger. If you don't have some mechanism to remove the player once the vote is cast, then they will be adding 30-60 votes per second, depending on FPS.

Comment: Is there a different piece of code I should be using for 2d? Probably should've mentioned I'm working in 2d.

Comment: Indeed there is. `OnTriggerStay` is only for 3D physics bodies. What you're looking for is `OnTriggerStay2D` (or possibly `OnTriggerEnter2D` as per my note)

Comment: I looked up OnTriggerEnter2D and figured its the same as OnCollisionEnter2D in this case (I tried both anyways), and it's not registering the collision/trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Unity might not support the standard .NET BCL, you might want to look into Unity's console "log" functionality:

[enter link description here](http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/08/26/console-debugging-in-unity-made-easy/)

Either that or look into a proper logging solution like NLog, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Console.Write("One vote Added")` if you want to print different strings in the same line in the console. 
And if you want a new line every time you write to the console, use `Console.WriteLine("One Vote Added")`.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use  Console.WriteLine("Your message");
Moreover, but i'm not sure, you seem to be getting your transform tag, which is probably not what you intended to do

Comment: Don't forget to add :Using System at top of your file, if you want to use this fonctionnality